# Unable to run Mongo daemon

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am not being able to run `mongod`. I used this command :

> sudo service mongodb start

Which gives :

```
Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked.
```

The file `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` is empty. I tried pasting this:

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Service
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
User=mongodb
Group=mongodb
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

into it, but every time I save it (using `su`), it becomes empty again after closing the file.
Then I used :

> sudo service mongod start

(I created mongod.service in `/etc/systemd/system/` and put the required code in it.)
It gives this output :

```
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

I have been stuck at it for 2 hours now. I removed mongodb and installed from scratch but that didn't help either. What is the problem here? I am on `Ubuntu 16.04`.

Answer (score 0):

For the service, when it is returning an error saying that the service is "masked", try executing **sudo systemctl unmask mongodb**.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/770054/mongodb-3-2-doesnt-start-on-lubuntu-16-04lts-as-service

Comment: Did you try this:

Followed these instructions and tried to run sudo systemctl start mongodb, but received the following error message: "Failed to start mongodb.service: Unit mongodb.service is masked." Running "sudo systemctl unmask mongodb" fixed the error – Robert Townley Nov 29 at 15:23

Comment: No I hadn't seen that comment. It worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad to hear -- I know sometimes the services can be finicky, but was pretty sure the answer would resolve the issue.